# Como puedo generar gráficas(barras, pastel y lineal) en base a una base de datos, usando NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, netbeans, xampp

Quiero generar unas gráficas en base a unas calificaciones que se almacenan en una base de datos, pero el problema es que he buscado varios tutoriales pero ninguno genera gráficas en base a datos almacenados en una BD. Agradezco si me pueden ayudar a decirme como lo podría realizar.

Estoy trabajando con NetBeans, xampp, phpMyAdmin.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, lee [ask]

Comment: puedes utilizar la siguiente librería para mostrar indicadores en graficos desde tu base de datos. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api.html El siguiente link te muestra como utilizarlo. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKpafdasfwY Espero que te sirva. a mi me funcionó a la perfección en eclipse mars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes utilizar la siguiente librería para mostrar indicadores en graficos desde tu base de datos.

[image: pagina]

El siguiente link te muestra como utilizarlo.

[Video_Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKpafdasfwY)

Espero que te sirva. a mi me funcionó a la perfección en **eclipse mars**.